# Variable does not exist:Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, after-trigger

I'm getting a Variable does not exist:Trigger error on this trigger. What am I doing wrong in the code? Please assist

```
trigger calcClaim on Claim__c (after Insert, after Update, Before Delete){
set<Id> OccIds = new set<Id>();
    integer count = 0;
    for(Claim__c cl :(Trigger.IsDelete ? Trigger.old: Trigger.new) )
    {    
        decimal temp = 0.0;
        try{
          if(Trigger.IsDelete || Trigger.IsInsert || (Trigger.IsUpdate && cl.Initial_Estimate__c != Trigger.oldMap.get.(cl.id).Initial_Estimate__c))
       {
                OccIds.add(cl.Occurrence__c);
       }
     }
          Catch(exception e)
         {
    cl.adderror(e.getMessage());
         }
  } 

if(!(OccIds.isempty())){
    List<RK_Occurrence__c> occs  = ([SELECT id FROM RK_Occurrence__c where Id in :OccIds]);
    system.debug(occs);

    OccurenceClaimCalculator.calculateOcc(occs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do quote (cut and paste) the full error message in your questions: the details often matter.

Answer (score 8):

You have a typo:

```
Trigger.oldMap.get.(cl.id).Initial_Estimate__c
```

should be:

```
Trigger.oldMap.get(cl.id).Initial_Estimate__c
```

You probably also need to apply an explicit cast, like:

```
((Claim__c) Trigger.oldMap.get(cl.id)).Initial_Estimate__c
```

You'll find this sort of issue easily by using an appropriate IDE. For example, I found it be copy/pasting your code into the anonymous apex tool provided by [Illuminated Cloud](http://www.illuminatedcloud.com/). Other IDEs may be able to help you similarly.